# Return value of oci_parse

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

what will be the condition of if , where i want to execute some command  inside if ,if there is no row returned by the query.

```
<?php
  include_once('config.php');
  $db = oci_new_connect(ORAUSER,ORAPASS,"localhost/XE");
  $sql="select * from table_1 where id=3";
  $result=oci_parse($db,$sql);
  oci_result($result);

  if()
  {

  }
  else
  {

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [`oci_fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch.php):

```
// parse/bind your statement

if (oci_fetch($your_statement)) {
    ... // do something when there is rows
}    
else {
    ... // do something when there is no rows
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP refers to running statements that do not return rows, such as inserts, updates, procedures...

Answer (score 0):

After assigning the bind values with oci_parse(), you need to run the query with [oci_execute()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php). This is the function definition:

> bool oci_execute  ( resource
>   $statement  [, int $mode =
>   OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS  ] )
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Putting it all together:

```
<?php

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$res = oci_execute($stmt);
if( !$res ){
    $error = oci_error($stmt);
    echo "Error: " . $error['message'] . "\n";
}else{
    echo "OK\n";
}

?>
```