# How to fetch data from database based on selection in the dropdown using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, dropdown, selection

I am trying to fetch the details of the person selected in the dropdown on another page.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="cmxform" action ='functions/processform.php' id="Form1" method="post">
           <legend> Faculty Transaction Form</legend>
            <label for="addname">Please Select School</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="school" id="school">
                <?php
                $nameslist = $getschool->getSchool();
                oci_execute($nameslist, OCI_DEFAULT);
                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($nameslist, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['SCHOOLPROPERNAME'] . '">' . $row['SCHOOLPROPERNAME']. '</option>';
                }
                ?>
           </select>
            <label for="names">Please Select Name</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names1234">
               <option value='0' >Select Name</option>

        </select>
            <label for="names">Recall FTF in progress</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="ftf" id="ftf">
               <option value='0' >Select Name</option>

        </select>
            <p>Paid/Unpaid/Terminated:</p>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="paid" name="paid" value="paid" >
            <label for="paid">Paid</label>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="unpaid" name="unpaid" value="unpaid" >
            <label for="unpaid">Un-Paid</label>
            </div>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="terminated" name="terminated" value="terminated" >
            <label for="terminated">Terminated</label>
            </div>
        </form>
          <?php
         $report = $getschool->getftf();
        if (count($report) === 0) {
            echo "<tr>No Reports</tr>";
       } else {
            
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($report); $i++) {
               
                echo

                "
                    <a class=btn href='createftf.php?id=".$report[$i]['ID']. "'id='recallFTF'>Create FTF</a>
                        </tr>";
                ";
                
            }
       }
        
   
    
        ?>
```

queries.php

```
class Queries {
 public static function getftf() {   
    $dbUser = "xxxx";
    $dbPass = "xxxx";
    $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xxxx)))";
    $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
    $sql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * from tblFTF_Archive_Page1 ");
    if (oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT)){
     $result =   oci_fetch_array($sql, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);
     return $result;
   } else {
       return false;
    }  
}
 
}
       
 }
```

I'm trying to fetch the ID of the person that's selected in the second or third dropdown and then I will be fetching more details of the same person. With the above code I'm getting an error sayig "PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable".
I've referred to some similar questions here but none of them had an answer for my question. Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Do a `var_dump($report)` when you get that warning. What is `$report`? You might want to use `is_null` or `empty`. The message is clear yes? The `count` function only works on things that are 'countable'.

Comment: Can you show how do I use it? I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return value of oci\_parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185116/return-value-of-oci-parse)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation the [`oci_parse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php) function returns **"a statement handle on success, or FALSE on error"**.

If you wrote the code `count(false);` you would get the warning you describe.

There are numerous ways to resolve what you've encountered. You need to know what a function might return and account for that. This is always the case!

So, you could do the following for example.

```
<?php
$report = $getschool->getftf();
if ($report === false || count($report) === 0) {
  echo "<tr>No Reports</tr>";
} else { 
...
```

That way you've checked the returned value is not Boolean `false` (might want to check for an error or see what went wrong). You then assume the returned value is a resource and is `countable` so you proceed to use `count`.

Inversely you could test for it being explicitly what you expect. See [`is_resource`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-resource.php)

**Update:**
Seeing now you are missing code... you need to use `oci_execute` and a `fetch` on the statement you prepared.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Yes the function is supposed to return all the information from the table. Further, I will be fetching the information of the person being selected in a form. Do you know what to do that?

Comment: In the above code I'm trying to fetch the ID of the person being selected in the dropdown

Comment: You need to *execute* and the *fetch*. Look at more examples.

Comment: Yes I did put an execute and fetch statement. It is still not fetching the ID. I'm editing the above code. PLease check

Comment: I still fail to see any `fetch_` function employed there.

Comment: updated the code. Please see. Now i get an error saying "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0"